# How do I make the second return for the second method work?

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm trying to make the `by_three?` method return false for all numbers not evenly divisible by three:

```
def greeter(name)
    return 'hi there ' + name
end 

def by_three?(number)
    return true if number/3 
    return false if number !=/3
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the modulo operator `%`:

```
def by_three?(number)
  if number % 3 == 0
    return true
  else  
    return false 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you do not need `return` statement in your case. Ruby methods automatically return the value of the last statement. `return` is only needed when breaking out of the method early. In your case, it would be:

```
def divisible? number, divisor
  number % divisor == 0
end

def divisible_by_three? number
  divisible? number, 3
end
```